# Setuptools and Pyproject.toml: specify source?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am defining a python project using a `pyproject.toml` file. No `setup.py`, no `setup.cfg`.

The project has dependencies on an alternate repository: `https://artifactory.mypypy.com`, how do I specify it ?

Comment: In short, you can't. You need to document it so that users of your project know where to find the dependencies and how to install them. That is the way it is, there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put this in pyproject.toml:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal-repo-2"
url = "https://<private-repo-2>"
priority = "explicit"
```

There are alternative for priority but they come with a security risk: an attacker who learns the name of your internal package can push a package of the same name to PyPI, and it will then become part of your executable.

Answer (score 2):

The dependency is independent on where it is hosted, the dependency is on the package not the repository.

The correct way to remediate the problem is to change your pip configuration to look in multiple repositories using the `extra-index-url` setting. This can be done either in your pip.conf or by specifying `--extra-index-url` on the pip command line.